# How can I get the largest contour out of an openCV function so that I can store it in an array

Tags: opencv

I want to get the largest contour out of the below function. I am using openCV and I am not familiar with the language used below. I only need the contour so that I can put it into an array for further processing. I guess I need to add some code in the first line and the last line. Also, what datatype is the contour? Here is the code:

```
+(UIImage *)ConvertImage:(UIImage *)image {
cv::Mat mat;
UIImageToMat(image, mat);

//. ......lots of image processing


std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
cv::Mat contourOutput = adaptive.clone();
cv::findContours( contourOutput, contours, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE );
int largest_area=0;
int largest_contour_index=0;
// iterate through each contour.
for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ )
{
    //  Find the area of contour
    double a=contourArea( contours[i],false);
    if(a>largest_area){
        largest_area=a;                  //this is the output I want to store
        largest_contour_index=i;

    }
}
UIImage *binImg = MatToUIImage(contourImage);
return binImg;
}
```

Comment: Do you really know what you want to get？ The max-area contour , or the max area of contours, the binary mask of max-area contour ?

Comment: I want the max area contour and I need it in the return statement together with the image (binImg), I guess as an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the contours are stored in the vector `std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;`
and the index of the largest one is `largest_contour_index`. 
Therefore create a `vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;` and blank `Mat biggest_contour;`, and then draw the contour on to it using its index like such: `drawContours(biggest_contour, contours, largest_contour_index, Scalar(255, 255, 255), CV_FILLED, 8, hierarchy);`

Comment: OK, that makes sense. However, how do I get the contour out of the function? So, I want to return an array with the image and the largest contour.

Comment: I did something like this ....NSMutableArray *returnArray = [binImg, contours], then changed the first line fo the function to +(NSMutableArray *)ConvertImage:(UIImage *)image {....... and the last line to    return returnArray;

Comment: but the above gives me an error in the return line saying "Expected body of lambda expression"